# How to search files with Doxygen

Tags: html, documentation, javadoc, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm using Doxygen to create documentation to my project.
This tool is wonderful except an issue I have with the searching function.
When I try to use the search box he find files and function that starting with the letters I wrote.
I will explain..
I have 3 files in my project:

1. BaseTemplate.java
2. RegularTemplate.java
3. CustomTemplate.java

when I write 'Template' in the search box he didn't find anything. This because he search items(function, files, etc.) only by prefix.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The normal doxygen search is quite a simple search and starts matching from the beginning. Doxygen has some more search capabilities (I didn't use them), please see the chapter "Searching" in the documentation.

Comment: I already saw this chapter and search other threads in google. nothing found.